# Значение предложения с оборотом обособленной запятыми

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение, значение

Есть такое предложение:

> Для авиапассажиров 2019 стал одним из самых безопасных годов в
>   истории, а также завершением десятилетия, в котором погибло меньше
>   людей, чем в любом другом с начала эры реактивных пассажирских
>   перевозок.

Что имел ввиду автор?

1. Что это десятилетие было самое безопасное с начал эры?
2. Что десятилетие окончилось, и в 2019 году погибло меньше людей чем в
   любом другом году с начала эры?

Как правильно раставить знаки в данных случаях?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые поставлены верно, но смысл сообщения недостаточно ясен.

Вариант редактирования:

*Для авиапассажиров 2019 год стал одним из самых безопасных  **за всю историю реактивных пассажирских перевозок**, а также завершением десятилетия **с минимальным количеством погибших за этот период людей.***